# Selecting from currently selected features using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-location

When using ArcMap there is an option of selecting from currently selected features.

What is the equivalent of that when i want to automate the process?

Below is some sample code but its not showing the required results:

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("SplitContours","cont_lyr")
arcpy.Buffer_analysis("River","Stream_buffer",200)
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("cont_lyr","INTERSECT",MaximumCentralPoints,"","NEW_SELECTION")
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("cont_lyr","INTERSECT","River","","NEW_SELECTION")
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('cont_lyr',workspace,'channel')
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 3):

Change `"NEW_SELECTION"` to `"SUBSET_SELECTION"`. See [help section](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm) of Select by location:

> SUBSET_SELECTION —The resulting selection is combined with the
>   existing selection.